# [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]みたいなリストを作成したい

Tags: python, python3

python3にて，例えばN=3, M=4として，

```
l = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]
```

みたいなリストを作成したいと考えています．
(1がN個, 2がN個, ..., MがN個)

このようなリストを作成する最も短いコードを教えていただきたいです．現在は

```
l = list(chain.from_iterable([[i]*N for i in range(1, M+1)]))
```

と書いています．一度間違った階層構造のリストを作ってからflattenしているのが気持ち悪いのですが，これより短く記述するのは難しいでしょうか．

Comment: numpy を使ってもよいのであれば、`numpy.repeat(range(1, M+1), N).tolist()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

内包表記2段でどうでしょう。

```
>>> M = 4
>>> N = 3
>>> [x+1 for x in range(M) for y in range(N)]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

おまけ。

itertools.chain_from_iterable を使う例

```
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[x+1]*N for x in range(M)]))
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

itertools.product を使う例

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [x+1 for x,y in itertools.product(range(M), range(N))]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
l = [i // n + 1 for i in range(n * m)]
```

で。

```
>>> m = 4
>>> n = 3
>>> l = [i // n + 1 for i in range(n * m)]
>>> l
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
>>> m = 5
>>> n = 4
>>> l = [i // n + 1 for i in range(n * m)]
>>> l
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```